# Using sed to replace the 1st ";" of a line with a string and then the 2nd ";" with another string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a semicolon separated playlist in the following format:

`Thåström ; Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209`

I want to replace the first `;` with a dash (-) and the 2nd `;` with the string "- Album: "

I'm trying with the following construction but it's not right:
`sed 's/\;/\-/1;s/\;/\-\ Album\:/2'`

Bur results are:

`Thåström - Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209`

I know the wrong part is in the first segment, because if I only run `sed 's/\;/\-\ "Album\:"/2'` I get the correct results at the end of the line:

`Thåström ; Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209`

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running this on the stock 'sed' in MacOS 13.5.2

I think you are very close to having what you want. I went with a construction that just used two expressions specified on the command line. You could also put these into a file and use the `-f <command_file>` option instead if you prefer

```
sed -e 's/;/-/' -e 's/;/- Album:/'
```

The first expression will make the substitution with the first semicolon on the line. The second expression changes the next. Since they are processed sequentially, I don't have to worry about specifying a numeric flag at the end as your sample does.

Example with an extra blank line to separate the output.

```
echo 'Thåström ; Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209' \
| sed -e 's/;/-/' -e 's/;/- Album:/' 

Thåström - Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209
```

**ETA:** In your original example, the second expression has a `2` as a flag. That will be replacing the second `;`. However, your first substitution replaced the first `;` so your command is trying to replace the *third* `;` on the line. If you just drop that `2` it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. however I don't quite get the explanation about my original example. I have specified the 1st occurrence on the first expression,I think!

Comment: @mariano-daniel - You have two substitution commands. The first says "replace the first ; with X" and the second says "replace the second ; with X". As a person, you are reading the commands as a unit and mentally applying them to the input simultaneously. The program does it sequentially and each command changes the input. So it does the first command (now you only have one ; left) and the second command does nothing because there is only one ; remaining.

Each command works in isolation as you want. It is the composition that has a problem. Flip the order (2nd, 1st) and they would work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, now I do understand. By replacing the first iteration of ";" there's no more second ";" to replace. I get it! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`:

```
$ awk '{ sub(/;/,"-"); sub(/;/, "- Album:")}1' file       

$ awk '{ print gensub(/(^[^;]*);([^;]*);(.*)/, "\\1-\\2- Album:\\3", g);}' file
```

To replace same pattern with different strings multiple times then the following may be used.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ar[1]="-"; ar[2]="- Album:";}{r=$0; for(i=1;i<=length(ar);i++) r=gensub(/;/, ar[i], 1, r); print r}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'S/ \; /-/ andthen S/ \; /- Album:/.put;'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family of programming languages. Above you use the `-ne` linewise non-autoprinting command-line flags, and simply perform two consecutive `S///` substitutions followed by out`put`. The `put` call adds the newline at the end of the line for you.

Sample Input:

```
Thåström ; Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209
```

Sample Output:

```
Thåström - Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209
```

The *really nice* aspect of Raku is that it's Unicode-ready. So you can use Unicode-characteristics to filter and/or substitute your text:

```
~$ raku -ne 'S/ \; /-/ andthen S/ \; /- Album:/ andthen S/ <:Script<Runic>>+ /⁒/.put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
16F1 ᛱ Thåström ; Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209
16F2 ᛲ Thåström ; Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209
16F3 ᛳ Thåström ; Stjärna som är din ; Skebokvarnsv. 209
```

Sample Output:

```
16F1 ⁒ Thåström - Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209
16F2 ⁒ Thåström - Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209
16F3 ⁒ Thåström - Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209
```

Above, three Runic letters are inserted into the Sample Input. Raku regexes can identify and/or filter-out characters based upon their ***Unicode-Script*** designation ( in this case `<:Script<Runic>>` ). Even though StackOverflow appears unable to display them, the Runic letters are properly substituted with the Unicode `⁒` "Commercial Minus Sign" ( U+2052 ).

https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U16A0.pdf
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Comment: Thank you @jubilatious1! This a pretty interesting alternative, mostly when dealing with music files as they tend to have quite unusual characters in them!

Comment: Ha, @mariano-daniel, but probably not Runic letters! I'll try to include some of these Unicode musical symbols next time: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

Comment: Very true, although (super coincidence) at the time I'm listening to "Vertur úlfur" by Icelandic singer EmilianaTorrini, not Runic but quite close ;-) Sorry for the offtopic and thanks for the link, I am reading it!

Comment: @mariano-daniel feel free to post a separate question on Unicode character identification/manipulation (e.g. Musical Symbols). You might be pleasantly surprised at the power fo  Raku's regex engine!

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/;\([^;]*\);/-\1- Album:/' file
Thåström - Stjärna som är din - Album: Skebokvarnsv. 209
```